# rspec with change method returning wrong number of arguments 0 for 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying this test.

## model

```
def self.tweet(url)
  Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = APP_CONFIG['twitter_consumer_key']
    config.consumer_secret = APP_CONFIG['twitter_consumer_secret']
    config.oauth_token = APP_CONFIG['twitter_access_token']
    config.oauth_token_secret = APP_CONFIG['twitter_secret_token']
  end    
  shorted_url = shorten_url(url)
  Twitter.update("#{title} - #{shorted_url}")
end

def self.shorten_url(url)
  authorize = UrlShortener::Authorize.new APP_CONFIG['bit_ly_id'], APP_CONFIG['bit_ly_api_key']
  client = UrlShortener::Client.new authorize
  shorten_url = client.shorten(url).urls
end

def publish(url)
  update_attributes(:available => true, :locked => false)
  tweet(url)
end
```

for now, I trying to test the last method, "publish" but I'm getting wrong number of arguments error message.

and on the test side, I have this:

```
describe Job, "publish" do

  it "should publish a job" do
    @job = Factory(:job)
    @job.publish.should change(Job.available).from(false).to(true)
  end

end
```

and the error message:

```
1) Job Job publish should publish a job
     Failure/Error: @job.publish.should change(Job.available).from(false).to(true)
     wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
     # ./app/models/job.rb:60:in `publish'
     # ./spec/models/job_spec.rb:128:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.12 seconds
47 examples, 1 failure, 4 pending
```

Appreciate  any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting it in a lambda:

```
lambda { @job.publish }.should change(Job.available).from(false).to(true)
```

Also, I'm not sure since I can't see all of your Model's code, but did you mean to use `@job.available` instead of `Job.available`?

**Edit**: You may need to use this format:

```
lambda { @job.publish }.should change(@job, :available).from(false).to(true)
```

Comment: yes, @job.available, because I didn't used self method. Am I right? Let me test your suggestion!